# Sum function of series of functions

Tags: sequences-and-series

For $x\in[0,1]$, what is
$$S(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac x{(k+x^2)^2}?$$
I tried to find this sum by breaking into partial fraction. But not able to find the sum.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to find this sum by breaking into partial fraction. But not able to find the sum.

Comment: put the partial fraction expansion that you got in the original question

Comment: Partial fractions can't be applied; the displayed summand is already fully factored.

Answer (score 3):

This boils down to the [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function), particularly,

$$S(x)=x\zeta(2,x^2+1)$$

It may also be written in terms of the [trigamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function),

$$S(x)=x\psi_1(x^2+1)$$

where

$$\psi_1(x)=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\ln(\Gamma(x))$$

You may be interested in viewing the [special values](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigammaFunction.html).

Comment: You missed the $k=0$ term.

Comment: @gammatester What do you mean?

Comment: (If you mean there's a $k=0$ term in the functions I mentioned, yes, I did account for them through that small little "+1" you see in the function arguments after the $x^2$)

Comment: Hurwitz zeta summation starts with $k=0$, the given sum starts at $k=1$

Comment: @gammatester $$\zeta(2,x^2+1)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(k+x^2+1)^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(k+x^2)^2}$$

Comment: OK, shame on me.

Comment: No problem @gammatester

Answer (score 1):

$$S(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac x{(k+x^2)^2}=x (\psi^{(1)}(1+x^2)-\psi^{(1)} (n+1+x^2))$$ 
$$T(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac x{(k+x^2)^2}=x \psi^{(1)}(1+x^2)$$ 
where appears the first derivative of the digamma function.

Comment: Where's the $n$ coming in?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt. I thought that the summation was up to $n$

Comment: :-/ That's strange, because you yourself wrote the sum up to $\infty$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt. Being almost blind, there are many mistakes from my side; fortunately, good people (like you) tell me about. Thanks and cheers.

Comment: $\ddot\smile$ Cheers and (+1) to you too.

Comment: Actually , I don't  know about this function much. Can someone simply tell me how to find sum of this using any kind arithmetic calculation.

Comment: @User420 The function exists because there is no simple way of finding its values.  If you provided a specific value of $x$, we could, but you should ask that as a new question instead.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt. I know what did happen : I did "read" $n$ and copy/paste the lhs (I am a lazy man) !! This must be related to my age and to a man I remember only the start of last name :  Alzheim.. (joke, I hope !)

Comment: (Lol, don't worry, I do the same all the time hehe)